# prevent users on the server from viewing anything in the git repository

Tags: git, gitea

I have a gitea git server installed.
how can I prevent the execution of commands in the cli on the linux server: git push, git pull, git clone and other commands that allow the user to view the repository and its contents (repository branches, etc.)?

Thus, I want to set a ban for users on the server to view anything in the git through the Linux server (then they will be able to view the repositories only through the web interface of the gitea)

Comment: This isn't a programming question, but a server question. Consider asking on superuser.com?

Comment: i will try, thank u!

Answer (score 0):

On the server you can restrict access to git for the specified user like this:

```
sudo setfacl -m u:john:--- /usr/bin/git
```